# factorizing characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

is there a way trick (an easy way except for the normal path) I can find the characteristic polynomial of a matrix factorized, I hate when I stuck with the factorization!

Comment: Factorizing a characteristic polynomial is exactly as hard as factorizing any other polynomial. If degree is greater than $2$, then Rational Root Theorem can help you finding roots, especially if you are solving exam-like problems. That and Ruffini's method for fast division should help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We do get lots of questions where it is easier to find the eigenvalues than to deal with the characteristic polynomial as a whole.